# How to use typescript with the definition of custom styles for a select using react-select

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I'd like to know how to nicely add types to a Select using react-select.

The component so far looks like this:

```
const Select: React.FC<Select> = (
  {defaultValue, onChange, options}: Select) => (
  <ReactSelect
    styles={selectStyles}
    …
  </ReactSelect>
```

and the definition of `selectStyles`:

```
interface HoverProps {
  bowShadow: string
  border: string
}

interface ControlComponentCSSProperties extends CSSProperties {
  '&:hover': HoverProps
}

const selectStyles = {
  control: (
    provided: CSSProperties,
    state: Props<{label: string; value: string}> | Props<Record<string, unknown>>
  ): ControlComponentCSSProperties => ({
    ...provided,
    '&:hover': {
      bowShadow: 'none',
      border: 'none',
    },
    border: 'none',
    borderRadius: input.border.radius,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: state.menuIsOpen ? 0 : input.border.radius,
    borderBottomRightRadius: state.menuIsOpen ? 0 : input.border.radius,
    …
```

This passes `tsc` but surely there are simpler ways to type this `selectStyles` object.

Would appreciate your help pointing me in a better direction.
Cheers!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can type the whole style object by using `StyleConfig` which removes the need to type every params manually. But before that you'll need to install `@types/react-select` package.

`StyleConfig` requires you to pass at least 2 generic type variables according to this declaration [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/2c47d99d3e8f90aa974111094f07832cc2f34de1/types/react-select/src/styles.d.ts#L23-L25).

- `OptionType`: The option type of `react-select`. According to [this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/2c47d99d3e8f90aa974111094f07832cc2f34de1/types/react-select/src/stateManager.d.ts#L45), the default `OptionType` is `{ label: string; value: string }`
- `IsMulti`: a boolean value to determine if you can select multiple values.

Putting it all together, we'll have something like this:

```js
import Select, { StylesConfig } from 'react-select';

type MyOptionType = {
  label: string;
  value: string;
};

const options: MyOptionType[] = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
];

const customControlStyles: CSSProperties = {
  color: "white",
  borderColor: "pink"
};

type IsMulti = false;

const selectStyle: StylesConfig<MyOptionType, IsMulti> = {
  control: (provided, state) => {
    // provided has CSSObject type
    // state has ControlProps type

    // return type is CSSObject which means this line will throw error if uncommented
    // return false;

    return {
      ...provided,
      ...customControlStyles
    };
  }
};
```

```js
export function App() {
  return (
    <Select options={options} styles={selectStyle} />
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 63696310/how-to-use-typescript-with-the-definition-of-custom-styles-for-a-select-using-re]

Comment: Thank you very much. 

I still had to use 

```
    state: Props<Record<string, unknown>>
```

as variations on ControlProps did not go through.

But your suggestion cleaned up the implementation a lot, appreciate it 

Comment: Thanks @gusaiani for this comment, i still need to use that too, because StylesConfig requires other 2 to 3 types

Comment: Just for the record: StylesConfig's first two generics are an OptionTypeBase extended type, and the second is a boolean referring to IsMulti.

Comment: @BenedekSimo Updated the answer to correct all of the issues. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: we still need something for the third/fourth prop to StylesConfig

Comment: I am getting `Type 'StylesConfig' is not generic` Type error

Comment: @Jyothu 1. Did you install `@types/react-select`? 2. What's your `react-select` version?

Comment: @NearHuscarl `react-select` version is `3.1.1`.  `@types/react-select` is `3.0.27`

Comment: @NearHuscarl this is great. Are these types on their web site?

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your custom styles in this way:

```
const borderStyle: StylesConfig<SelectItemType, boolean, GroupBase<SelectItemType>> = useMemo(() => ({
      control: (base: CSSObjectWithLabel) => ({
        ...base,
        borderColor: error ? '#d32f2f' : 'rgb(204, 204, 204)',
        boxShadow: "none",
      }),
      placeholder: (base: CSSObjectWithLabel) => ({
        ...base,
        color: error? '#d32f2f' : 'hsl(0, 0%, 50%)'
      })
}), [error])
```

And pass this as 'styles' prop of React Select