# React-select typescript upgrade 3 to 4

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

With version 3 I had some code like this:

```
export const selectCustomStyles: StylesConfig = {
  control: (base) => ({
    ...base,
    background: 'white',
  }),
  option: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    color: 'white',
  })
};

export const selectCustomTheme = (theme: Theme): Theme => {
  return {
    ...theme,
    colors: {
      ...theme.colors,
      primary: '#185135',
    }
  };
};
```

And my Selects works ok, like this one:

```
import Select, { NamedProps } from 'react-select';
import { selectCustomStyles, selectCustomTheme } from '../../utils';
// Agent is some interface different than { value: string, label: string }    

type SelectAgentProps = NamedProps<Agent>

const SelectAgent: React.FC<SelectAgentProps> = ({ ...rest }) => {
  return (
      <Select
        styles={selectCustomStyles}
        theme={selectCustomTheme}
        {...rest}
        getOptionLabel={(agent) => agent.name}
        getOptionValue={(agent) => agent.code}
      />
  );
};

export default SelectAgent;
```

But now with the version 4, I had to pass 2 generics to `StylesConfig` type, like this:

```
StylesConfig<MyOptionType, IsMulti>
```

I'm trying to define thos types with:

```
export type MyOptionType = {
  [key: string]: string | undefined;
}

type IsMulti = false;
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: (StateProps<Props<Agent, false, GroupTypeBase<Agent>>> &     import("/home/paulo/Documents/afex/afex-connect-web/node_modules/@types/react-    select/src/stateManager").Props<...> & import("/home/paulo/Documents/afex/afex-connect-    web/node_modules/@types/react-select/src/Select").Props<...>) | Readonly<...>): StateManager<...>', gave the     following error.
    Type 'Partial<Styles<MyOptionType, false, GroupTypeBase<MyOptionType>>>' is not assignable to type     'Partial<Styles<Agent, false, GroupTypeBase<Agent>>>'.
      Types of property 'clearIndicator' are incompatible.
        Type '((base: CSSObject, props: IndicatorProps<MyOptionType, false, GroupTypeBase<MyOptionType>>) =>     CSSObject) | undefined' is not assignable to type '((base: CSSObject, props: IndicatorProps<Agent, false,     GroupTypeBase<Agent>>) => CSSObject) | undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StateProps<Props<Agent, false, GroupTypeBase<Agent>>> &     import("/home/paulo/Documents/afex/afex-connect-web/node_modules/@types/react-    select/src/stateManager").Props<...> & import("/home/paulo/Documents/afex/afex-connect-    web/node_modules/@types/react-select/src/Select").Props<...>, context: any): StateManager<...>', gave the     following error.
    Type 'Partial<Styles<MyOptionType, false, GroupTypeBase<MyOptionType>>>' is not assignable to type     'Partial<Styles<Agent, false, GroupTypeBase<Agent>>>'.  TS2769

  11 |       <Select
  12 |         className='dropDownSelectAgent'
> 13 |         styles={selectCustomStyles}
     |         ^
  14 |         theme={selectCustomTheme}
  15 |         {...rest}
  16 |         getOptionLabel={(agent) => agent.name}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: did you ever find a solution here?

Comment: @peterflanagan No, I had to keep using the old version, and refactor a lot of code made for the new one. Now I'm not working with that typescript project, it was more time spent dealing with types and stuff that using with pure javascript and fixing some "types" errors. Tired of getting errors from 3rd party libraries and it major changes...

Comment: if you put the `styles` inline and not as an object defined separately it works without complaining. Pretty annoying tbh :-D

Answer (score 2):

i've gotten it to work by following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63696310/how-to-use-typescript-with-the-definition-of-custom-styles-for-a-select-using-re) except using CSSObject instead of CSSProperties

```
import { CSSObject } from '@emotion/serialize';
import Select, { StylesConfig } from 'react-select';

type MyOptionType = {
  label: string;
  value: string;
};

const options: MyOptionType[] = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
];

const customControlStyles: CSSObject = {
  color: "white",
  borderColor: "pink"
};

type IsMulti = false;

const selectStyle: StylesConfig<MyOptionType, IsMulti> = {
  control: (provided, state) => {
    return {
      ...provided,
      ...customControlStyles
    };
  }
};
```